# Understanding this property of the digamma function: $\psi(n + \frac{1}{2}) = -\gamma - 2\ln 2 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{2}{2k-1}$

Tags: harmonic-numbers, digamma-function

I am reading through the Wikipedia article on the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) where the digamma function is [compared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers) to the Harmonic Numbers defined as $H_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k}$.

The first equation is well explained and clear to me:

$$\psi(n) = H_{n-1} - \gamma$$

It's the last equation which is not clear to me from the argument:

$$\psi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) = -\gamma -2\ln 2 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{2k-1}$$

How does this equation follow from the explanation that came before?

Could someone help me to understand why it is true?

Comment: Larry, Most of this is collected in Abramowitz and Stegun  which was first published in 1964 and reprinted later. This may be the whole thing in a pdf worth checking. I have the Dover reprint.  http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$ gives $\psi(s+1)=\psi(s)+1/s$, $\psi(n+1/2) =\psi(1/2)+ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k-1/2}$ so it is just saying that $\psi(1/2)=-\gamma -2\log 2$ which follows from the explicit formula $\psi(z)=-\gamma-\sum_n \frac1{z+n}-\frac1{n+1}$ and the expansion of $\log (1+x),x\to 1$